# Decode suspected timestamps

Tags: binary, reverse-engineering, decoding, binary-data

I'm writing a tool to decode data I retrieve via mini-USB cable from the Beurer BF-105 scale.

The part I'm really struggling with are the 4 bytes that I think should encode the timestamp of the measurements.

I gathered the following example data over the last 3 days:

```
00101101 10001001 10001111 11111100 = 2024-03-17 ~11:00
00101101 10001001 11001000 01110101 = 2024-03-17 15:28:24 (?)
00101101 10001010 10101000 01001100 = 2024-03-18 07:21
00101101 10001010 10110001 10011110 = 2024-03-18 07:23
00101101 10001011 00111111 10000110 = 2024-03-18 18:08:13
00101101 10001011 01000000 00110010 = 2024-03-18 18:10:39
00101101 10001011 11100110 00010000 = 2024-03-19 05:58:23
00101101 10001011 11111010 01001110 = 2024-03-19 07:24:46

00101101 10001001 10011011 11101000 = 2024-03-17 ~16:00
00101101 10001010 10011110 00000001 = 2024-03-18 ~07:00
00101101 10001011 11101101 10010100 = 2024-03-19 06:30:20
00101101 10001011 11101101 10101010 = 2024-03-19 06:30:54
```

The one thing I do see in there is that at least the lower few bits of the second byte encodes the day, since it increases by one on every day change. But I don't understand how it encodes it.

Does anybody see any patterns here that I'm missing? What could those bits want to tell me?

I've started modifying the tool I created for the BF-100 to the different encoding of the BF-105 here:
https://gitlab.com/thomas351/beurer_bf100_parser/-/blob/bf105/src/main.rs

Unlike the birthday storage in the user section and the retrieval time at the end of the file, it's clearly not just encoding the 3 usual parts of our calendar (year, month & day) separately without any offset. Interpreting the whole first 2 bytes as a single u16 integer gives the values 11657, 11658 & 11659 for the last 3 days. Interpreting it like that would fit the data I have collected so far, but make day zero 1992-04-17 - which doesn't seem like a sensible offset to use.

## UPDATE:

as @htmlcoderexe pointed out, the switch between the day does not happen at midnight, but some-when between ~11:00 and 18:08. Or according to my two newly aquired samples some-when between ~11:00 and 17:50:

```
00101101 10001100 10001100 11100011 = 2024-03-19 17:50:09
00101101 10001100 10001101 00000001 = 2024-03-19 17:51:30
```

Comment: not sure it is that simple. The day change seems to not occur at 00:00 -  the data says best guess is around 18:00 (see the stamps on 2024-03-18, the lower bits of the second byte differ by 1 before and after, and after 18:00 they're the same as on 2024-03-19 but before 18:00)
However, the other numbers seem to roll over weirdly, as just 8 and 10 minutes past 18:00 already shows high values in 3rd byte. Maybe some of those are flags? I suspect this might actually be counting some "ticks" not really aligned to human readable time units.

Comment: oh, you're right, I didn't see that before, thanks for the hint. Well I'm unsure what information those 4 bytes contain, the previous model only encoded the date and not the time. Also in a not really straight forward encoding I was able to copy from here: https://github.com/Urban82/BeurerScaleManager/wiki/Analysis

Comment: where do you get the timestamps from? as in, how do you know that those binary values correspond to those specific timestamps, and why sometimes it is precise down to the second and sometimes not even the minute (i.e. "~11:00")

Comment: those timestamps are just what I've manually collected, so the sub-minute part will most likely either not be encoded in the binary data at all or at least not match up with what I noted down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. It's an u32 that represents the seconds passed since 2000-01-01 00:00:00.